# In grid view I want to add condition but it always return 0.00

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="debite">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="stat_amount" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag")=="d" ) ? Eval("stat_amount"): "0.00" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

In grid view I want to add condition but it always return 0.00 ( I want if the v_flag = c then return v_amount else return 0 and this my html but  it always return 0.00)

Comment: Are you sure that the condition that you have stated in your question is the same as in the code? Because in the post it is not same, I mean the variable names.

Comment: Or is there a value equal `d` in `stat_flag` field.

Comment: sorry i mean  I want if the stat_flag == c then return stat_amount else return 0 and this my html but it always return 0.00

Comment: yaa there is a value d stat_flag  in database

Comment: @rawan you said you wanna check `stat_flag` with `c` but in your code you check it with `d`, you mean it doesn't work anyway ?

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="credit">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="stat" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag") == "c" ) ? Eval("stat_amount") : "0.00" %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="debit">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="stat_amount" runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("stat_flag") == "d") ? Eval("stat_amount") : "0.00"  %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right it always return `0.00` , Your problem is because of `Eval` you should compare `d` with `ToString` of `Eval` it will work fine
so change the code as following:

```
 <asp:Label ID="stat_amount" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("stat_flag").ToString() =="d" ) ? Eval("stat_amount"): "0.00" %>'></asp:Label>
```